# pushing project to a newly created repository

Tags: android, git, visual-studio, android-studio

I've migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio.
Now I have created a new repository in Visual Studio for the Android Studio (2.0 version) project.
In Android Studio I have done the following :

1. Enabled "Version Control Integration"
2. Chose Git as the selected version control system (all the files' names turned red)
3. Added all the folders in the project to staging(They are all green now)
4. Now I'm a bit confused how do I link all of it to the repo I created? where do I place the visual studio url of the new repo  ? will it automatically push it all to a branch that will be called 'master' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
cd /path/to/project/
git init
git remote add origin yourgiturl
git push origin master
```

Comment: gui is provided by github or similar git project managers which can be used with projects on there server. command line will work everywhere, even if its your own git repo.

Comment: Visual Studio says the repo is still empty.

Comment: although when I repeated the `git push -u origin --all` I got a message in cmd :`fatal: remote origin already exists`

Comment: try this: `git push origin master`

Comment: it says `fatal: I don't handle protocol 'git@https'`

Comment: what is your `git` url?

Comment: try adding `SSH` version of the url. It would start with `git@`

Comment: before updating url, run this `git remote remove origin`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109637/discussion-between-bvtp-and-rohit-arya).